# RecyclerView not showing elements

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I recently started a new project on android studio. I switched to Kotlin and this language is giving me such a hard time!

I've set up a `RecyclerView` in my app and it's working fine. My adapter takes an `ArrayList` as an argument and displays all the data.

I have two functions here that create the ArrayList for my `adapter: cardMaker()` and `getEventsInfo()`. These two functions return an ArrayList with Cards elements.

When I call my adapter with an `ArrayList` created by `getEventsInfo` then all the events are showing fine.

But when I use `cardMaker()`, there are no events showing up!

I really can't understand what is going on here and it drives me crazy! ^^

If this language is really sequential by default, how is this behavior possible? I fell like I am missing something important here.

```
private fun cardMaker(): ArrayList<Card?> {
    var newCards: ArrayList<Card?> = arrayListOf()
    newCards.add(Card("UserCard", R.mipmap.logo_zenith_round, userData.firstName, userData.lastName))
    val infoCards = getEventsInfo()
    newCards.addAll(infoCards)

    return newCards
}

private fun getEventsInfo(): ArrayList<Card?> {
    var infoCards: ArrayList<Card?> = arrayListOf()
    db.collection("Events")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                val eventsInfo = Card("EventCard",
                    R.mipmap.logo_zenith_round,
                    "${document.get("Name")}",
                    "${document.get("Date")}")
                infoCards.add(eventsInfo)
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents.", exception)
        }
    return infoCards
}

cards = cardMaker()

// RecyclerView
linearLayoutManager = 
androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
adapter = RecyclerAdapter(cards)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
```

Comment: Can you mention the code which binds your Ui and data model? The ViewHolder which takes in your Card object and binds it so specific views?

Comment: I assume the trick is that `getEventsInfo()` returns an empty list ALWAYS because Firebase fetches things asynchronously

Comment: Thanks EpicPandaForce, I did some research on that and learn a few things thanks to you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was not related to Kotlin specificity.

As EpicPandaForce said: "Firebase fetches things asynchronously"

So I made a class instance of the variable cards: ArrayList and added adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in my getEventsInfo() method inside the OnSuccessListener.

It is now working perfectly.

Thank you!